# Is the state of any standard class after being moved specified?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

If I `move` `shared_ptr` 'a' into `shared_ptr` 'b' is 'a' guaranteed to be null?

Is the state of *any* standard class after being moved specified?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general 17.6.5.15/1 applies:

> Objects of types defined in the C++ standard library may be moved from (12.8). Move operations may be explicitly specified or implicitly generated. Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be placed in a valid but unspecified state.

Thus you can call any functions which requires no precondition.

If specified, [what @Xeo said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8522831/500104) applies.

Comment: I cross-referenced our answers, we both added one part of the complete answer. :)

Comment: After a move it is best to let the old object fall out of scope or explicitly re-initialize it before re-use. Relying on a method having no pre-conditions would become a maintenance problem (said the man holding the axe).

Answer (score 13):

If specified, it's under their constructor and (if assignable) assignment operator subclause. For `shared_ptr` we have:

`§20.7.2.2.1 [util.smartptr.shared.const]`

```
shared_ptr(shared_ptr&& r) noexcept;
template<class Y> shared_ptr(shared_ptr<Y>&& r) noexcept;
```

> p20 *Remark:* The second constructor shall not participate in overload resolution unless `Y*` is convertible to `T*`.
>   p21 *Effects:* Move-constructs a `shared_ptr` instance from `r`.
>   p22 *Postconditions:* `*this` shall contain the old value of `r`. `r` shall be *empty*. `r.get() == 0`.

The assignment operators of `shared_ptr` are basically describes by copy-and-swap with a temporary constructed from the (moved if rvalue) argument:

`§20.7.2.2.3 [util.smartptr.shared.assign]`

```
shared_ptr& operator=(shared_ptr&& r) noexcept;
template<class Y> shared_ptr& operator=(shared_ptr<Y>&& r) noexcept;
```

> p4 *Effects:* Equivalent to `shared_ptr(std::move(r)).swap(*this)`.
>   p5 *Returns:* `*this`.

If not specified, [what @AProgrammer said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8522879/500104) applies.

Comment: @Matthieu : Sounds like you need TCO. ;-]