# Getting an error, or at least a warning, when using a variable that has been std::move'ed elsewhere

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

This:

```
void foo(int &&r) {
  std::cout << r << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  int i = 2;
  foo(std::move(i));
  i = 3; //no warning. any way to get some warnings here?
  return 0;
}
```

Is there no way to tell the compiler to give me an error (or warning) if I accidentally use the variable after I have moved it? I think this would be very convenient. A lot of times I find myself moving variables elsewhere like that, but then I manually have to be VERY CAREFUL that I don't use them afterwards. Now this hasn't caused any problems yet, but who knows down the line... better be safe!

Maybe there are some preprocessor trickery (or pretty widely available compiler extensions) that exists to do this stuff?

---

More realistic example:

```
struct HugeStorage {
  std::vector<double> m_vec;
  HugeStorage(std::vector<double> vec) : m_vec(std::move(vec)) { }
};

struct SmallStorage {
  std::vector<double> m_vec;
  SmallStorage(std::vector<double> vec) : m_vec(std::move(vec)) { }
};

std::vector<double> vec_from_data_source() {
  return std::vector<double>(); //only example!!
}

int main() {
  std::vector<double> vec = vec_from_data_source();
  if (vec.size() > 10000)
  {
    HugeStorage storage(std::move(vec));
    //do some things, but I gotta be careful I don't do anything to vec
  }
  else
  {
    SmallStorage storage(std::move(vec));
    //do some things, but I gotta be careful I don't do anything to vec
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The variable hasn't been moved, just its value. There is absolutely nothing wrong in assigning it a new value.

Comment: What "trouble" do you foresee and what is the *actual* problem with the code you show?

Comment: @NikBougalis Updated with more realistic example

Comment: duplicate of [Warn if accessing moved object in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552690/warn-if-accessing-moved-object-in-c11)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there no way to tell the compiler to give me an error (or warning) if I accidentally use the variable after I have moved it?

The answer is **"no, there is no way"** (to the best of my knowledge at least, no currently available compiler offers such an option, and for a good reason - see below).

Even if that was possible at all, why would you expect a warning, or even worse an error, to be given in this case? First of all, moving from an integer is not any different than copying it.

Secondly, for *most* types, assigning a moved-from object of that type is a perfectly legal operation; this is always true of fundamental types like `int`, and it is definitely true of `std::vector`, although it might not be true of other types.

In general, whether or not assigning a moved-from object is legal depends on the particular post-conditions of the move operation for that type and on the preconditions of the assignment operator (the assignment operator for types of the Standard Library have no preconditions on the left-hand side argument). This is something a compiler cannot check in the general case.

Therefore, if you were to:

1. Move from an object for which the move assignment or move constructor places the moved-from object in an *unspecified state* (that's the case for `std::vector`), and then;
2. Invoke any function with *preconditions* on the state of that object (and that's **not** the case for the assignment to an `std::vector`);

That would certainly be bad. On the other hand, the compiler does not have a way to perform a *semantic analysis* of your program and find out whether this is the case:

```
A x, y;
...
if (complicatedCondition())
{
    y = move(x);
} 

foo(x); // Did I move from x? And if so, is it safe to call foo()?
```

Moreover, don't forget that the philosophy of C++ is to give you power and (most often) design guidelines, but "lets you shoot your feet" if you are really trying to do that.

There *are* dangerous, even meaningless things that you can do in C++ (will your compiler give you a warning, or an error, if you try to `delete` the same pointer twice?), but the language itself won't prevent you from doing them, under the assumption that you really, really know what you are doing.

Comment: For library types, there is no guarantee that the object is *assignable-to*, only that it is *destructible*. That being said, many library implementations will offer that additional guarantee over what the standard requires.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas:  17.6.5.15/p1 guarantees that all moved-from std::lib types will be in a valid but unspecified state.  That means that unless the types has a precondition on the lhs of an assignment statement, it can be assigned to, even after being moved from.  Note that this blanket statement applies to types in the std-lib, and not to types in general.  And I am not aware of any std::type that has a precondition on being assigned to.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: I was mistaken there. Just checked the standard and corroborated what you mention here. Won't remove the comment as that would make your comment an answer to *nothing*.

Answer (score 6):

```
//do some things, but I gotta be careful I don't do anything to vec
```

Clarification:  You need to be careful that you don't do anything to `vec` that requires a precondition.  You **can** do anything with `vec` that does **not** require any preconditions.  For example you can assign `vec` a new value.  You can call `vec.clear()`.  You can call `vec.size()`.  But do not call `vec.pop_back()` because that member function has a precondition.

Comment: In case it's not obvious to everyone, I would clarify that you can't do anything that requires a precondition _without checking that precondition first_. It's fine to call `if (!vec.empty()) vec.pop_back();` because after the call to `vec.empty()` you know the precondition is met